# JavaFx Updating UI based on notification from Java thread

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am new to multithreading, Java and JavaFx. I am building an application with JavaFX UI which updates a graph continously based on live data. Here is the current design,

**1. When a JavaFx button is pressed, I invoke a thread which sets up the framework to send requests and get responses**

```
    startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override 
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {             
            stopButton.setDisable(false);               

            if(!startButton.isDisable()){
                runSequence = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                 public void run() {
                    SynchThreads sharedObject = new SynchThreads();             
                    new Bridge(sharedObject);
                    startSequence = new Sequence(sharedObject);             
                    startSequence.performCalls();  

                    }                   
                });

                runSequence.start();

            }               
            startButton.setDisable(true);
        }
    });
```

**2. runSequence thread which is invoked as above invokes another thread "callbackThread" that constantly receives data. This data which is received is passed to runSequence thread for further processing**

```
    BusinessLogic businessLogic = new BusinessLogic();

    executor.submit(pduApiDllCallBackThread);//This collects the data in background

//Here we are back on runSequence thread that works on the collected data.  
         while(true){
        response = sharedObject.take();                 
        businessLogic.primeData(response);
    }
```

**3. The BusinessLogic class after working on this data notifies the user interface with an event ID and data that should be shown on the graph.**

```
  UI.notifyListeners(0, graphCoords);//here event ID is 0 and graphCoords is a HashMap
```

**4. In the user interface everytime I get the notification I update the LineChart by using Platform.runLater. This notification occurs every 4 millisecs. So, I end up doing a lot of Platform.runLater calls**

```
public void notifyListeners(int eventType, Map<Integer, Float> graphCoords) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
    //Old series is cleared. Showing dummy data being updated
                    series.getData().clear();
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("1", Math.random()+1));
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("3", Math.random()+5));
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("4", Math.random()-25));
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2", Math.random()-10));
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("-1", xxx));


        }

    });

}
```

**Please provide your expert tips if this is ok to do this or if there is a better way to handle this in UI.I do not have more control over the layer below UI which notifies the UI. As the notification occurs every 4ms I wanted to know if there is a better approach**

Any help is appreciated. Please help. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You might swamp the JavaFX event queue by executing Platform.runLater so often, so you might want to batch the responses up (say in groups of ten), then make a single runlater call for each batch.

There is a specific [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site on stackoverflow.

Make sure you have animation turned off on the chart so it doesn't try to do too much with each update.

Your solution does seem a bit complicated, but perhaps it's warranted for your situation, I don't know.

I don't know how you are handling your concurrency, but take a look at [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) and the [concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) if you haven't already.  Also checkout [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) if you have not already.  Sometimes the higher level `java.util.concurrent` framework is more expressive, less error prone, easier to work with and easier to reason about than the lower level object monitor wait/notify methods.

You may want to mark some of the threads you are using as [daemon threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29).  You may also want to add some logic to handle interruption of threads or cancellation of processes, similar to the examples in the JavaFX [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) documentation.

If you are new to Java, multithreading and JavaFX, starting off with a multithreaded, networked JavaFX app is jumping off the deep end.

Often, concurrent work is offloaded from the JavaFX application thread to worker threads using the [Task/Service framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks, between the threads that are getting the response and processing the response, I have a shared object and use a simple wait-notify mechanism as described in the oracle docs. My concern is about the interaction between the thread which is invoked on start button that has final result and JavaFx thread. Is there an alternate way to handle this ? Please suggest.

Comment: I don't have any concern about that interaction.

Comment: Hi Jewelsea, Thanks for the detailed response. Appreciate it. Have a Merry X-Mas and a Happy new year.